# UserCake/PHP - isUserLoggedIn won't work, gives blank page

Tags: php, authentication, usercake

I'm trying to check if the user is currently logged in or not.
If the user is logged in, I want to echo the correct `<li>`'s to the menu.

I tried doing this at the top of the page:

```
<?php

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once ('models/config.php');
//$username = $loggedInUser->username; 

if ($isUserLoggedIn()) {
    $r1 = $loggedInUser->username;
    $r2 = "Logout";
} else {
    $r1 = "Login";
    $r2 = "Register";
}
?>
```

and here's the `<li>` tags:

```
<li><a class="short" href="About" style="display: block;"><?php echo $r1 ?></a></li>
    <li><a class="short" href="About" style="display: block;"><?php echo $r2 ?></a></li>
```

Comment: try to echo a statement to check the code blocks. Use a boolean to save user's state.

Comment: You can also try userspice instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong code for checking is user is logged in or not, it's: **isUserLoggedIn**

Try this:

```
<?php

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once ('models/config.php');
//$username = $loggedInUser->username; 

if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
    $r1 = $loggedInUser->username;
    $r2 = "Logout";
} else {
    $r1 = "Login";
    $r2 = "Register";
}
?>
```